# Append records from one table to another using the common field

Tags: mysql, sql, merge

There are many varied posts about this matter, but I am unable to find the answer I need. I am hoping this question is unique.

I am trying to append all the data from one table to another, without creating new records. The data in the second table is really a subset of data for a portion of the existing records in the first table.

For example: 
I have the table "SPK". And I want to write all of the data from SPK into the table "RCT". The common field between each record I want to match is the RegID, which is unique in both tables (i.e. there is only one SPK record per RCT record).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you mean append the columns in one table (call it SECOND) to the other (call it FIRST).

In that case, does this work ?

```
UPDATE 
    regcontactsTest
    JOIN 
    speakersTest 
    ON speakersTest.RegistrationID = regcontactsTest.RegistrationID
SET regcontactsTest.presentationtitle = speakersTest.presentationtitle
```

EDIT: Updated the query based on Mariadb syntax

Comment: So I ran this exact query. But it is giving me this error:  *#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM speakersTest JOIN regcontactsTest ON speakersTest' at line 3*

`UPDATE regcontactsTest 
SET regcontactsTest.presentationtitle = speakersTest.presentationtitle
FROM 
    speakersTest
    JOIN 
    regcontactsTest  
      ON speakersTest.RegistrationID = regcontactsTest.RegistrationID`

Comment: Can you try with this :UPDATE regcontactsTest
JOIN speakersTest ON speakersTest.RegistrationID = regcontactsTest.RegistrationID
SET regcontactsTest.presentationtitle = speakersTest.presentationtitle

Comment: Hi again, I did the append today. One strange thing I noticed, when I click on the table, it shows *Showing rows 0 - 29 (16495 total, Query took 0.0003 sec) [field name: field content.......]* notification. Notice the brackets with one field name and content right after? I am not sure if something went wrong during the query. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JOIN. For general Update join :

```
 update tab1 a 
   join tab2 b ON a.join_colA = b.join_colB  
   SET a.columnToUpdate = [something]
```

Or in other words:

```
update
  tab1 a 
  join tab2 b on ..
set a.field=...;
```